# Как удалить определенные элементы коллекции с учетом сдвига

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist

Есть коллекция, состоящая из интовых чисел, и в ней нужно удалить чётные элементы.
Я попытался сделать это через цикл, но когда я удаляю элемент, индексы сдвигаются, и пропускается одно число, и получается, если все числа четные, то удаляются элементы через одного.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class col {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List nums = new ArrayList<>();
        nums.add(2);
        nums.add(4);
        nums.add(6);
        nums.add(8);
        nums.add(2);
        nums.add(10);
        nums.add(22);
        nums.add(12);
        print(nums);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 1; i++) {
            if ((Integer) nums.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
                nums.remove(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        print(nums);
    }

    public static void print(List list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print("[" + list.get(i) + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Удаляйте с конца или делайте поправку на количество удаленных

Comment: `List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();` - так правильней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее простой/лаконичный *современный* (Java 8+) способ удаления элементов из коллекции -- использовать метод [`Collection::removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-), в который следует передать функцию-предикат для определения удаляемых элементов.  Также для проверки на чётность можно проверять младший бит на равенство 0:

```java
List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2,3,4,6,8,10,22,-2,-5,0));
data.removeIf(n -> (n & 1) == 0); // [3, -5]
```

Упомянутый метод использует под капотом итератор и его метод [`Iterator::remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--), который как раз рекомендуется для безопасного удаления элементов из коллекции при прохождении по ней, так как позволяет избежать излишних сложностей с индексной арифметикой и проблем с `ConcurrentModificationException` со времён Java 1.2 и появления Collection Framework.

```java
List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2,3,4,6,8,10,22,-2,-5,0));
for (Iterator<Integer> it = data.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    if (0 == (it.next() & 1)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

---

Однако если стоит задача реализовать удаление именно с использованием индексов, можно удалять элементы с конца, согласно совета в комментариях:

```java
for (int i = data.size(); i-- > 0;) {
    if (data.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
        data.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Если же и такой вариант -- недопустимая хитрость, и нужен классический `for` цикл по индексам именно с начала списка, то коррекцию индексов и размера списка можно выполнить так:

```java
for (int i = 0, n = data.size(); i < n; i++) {
    if (data.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
        data.remove(i--); // коррекция индекса при удалении
        n--; // коррекция размера списка
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можешь изменять значения на null, а в методе print если объект == null то его не выводить.

Answer (score -1):

Я понял как это сделать, просто добавить проверку, похожую на сортировку пузырьком

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class col {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List nums = new ArrayList<>();
        nums.add(2);
        nums.add(4);
        nums.add(6);
        nums.add(8);
        nums.add(2);
        nums.add(10);
        nums.add(22);
        nums.add(12);
        print(nums);

        boolean norm = false;

        while (!norm) {
            norm = true;
            for (int i = 0; i <= nums.size() - 1; i++) {

                if (((Integer) nums.get(i) % 2) == 0) {
                    norm = false;
                    nums.remove(i);


                }


            }
        }
        print(nums);

    }
    public static void print(List list) {
        for (int i = 0;i<list.size()-1;i++){
            System.out.print("["+list.get(i)+"]");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Использование вложенных циклов для принудительной перепроверки списка -- совершенно лишнее; 2) Использовать нетипизированный "сырой" список, чтобы затем заниматься кастингом -- тоже, хотя достаточно сразу объявить его `List<Integer> nums`; 3) Метод `toString` _правильно_ переопределён для коллекций `System.out.println(nums);` и нет особой необходимости в реализации какого-то отдельного `print(List list)` метода, который к тому же _никогда_ не напечатает последний элемент любого списка.